# Accessing nested values in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json

In an app using react/redux, I made a GET request to Google's Civic Api and received the following object which I added to my state:

```js
{
   "kind":"civicinfo#representativeInfoResponse",
   "normalizedInput":{
      "line1":"11111 Random Address Way",
      "city":"Germantown",
      "state":"MD",
      "zip":"20874"
   },
   "divisions":{
      "ocd-division/country:us/state:md/cd:6":{
         "name":"Maryland's 6th congressional district",
         "officeIndices":[
            0
         ]
      }
   },
   "offices":[
      {
         "name":"United States House of Representatives MD-06",
         "divisionId":"ocd-division/country:us/state:md/cd:6",
         "levels":[
            "country"
         ],
         "roles":[
            "legislatorLowerBody"
         ],
         "officialIndices":[
            0
         ]
      }
   ],
   "officials":[
      {
         "name":"John K. Delaney",
         "address":[
            {
               "line1":"1632 Longworth House Office Building",
               "city":"Washington",
               "state":"DC",
               "zip":"20515"
            }
         ],
         "party":"Democratic",
         "phones":[
            "(202) 225-2721"
         ],
         "urls":[
            "http://delaney.house.gov/"
         ],
         "photoUrl":"http://bioguide.congress.gov/bioguide/photo/D/D000620.jpg",
         "channels":[
            {
               "type":"Facebook",
               "id":"congressmanjohndelaney"
            },
            {
               "type":"Twitter",
               "id":"RepJohnDelaney"
            },
            {
               "type":"YouTube",
               "id":"repjohndelaney"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am attempting to access the value for "name" but am unable to so. I am able to access the objects for "kind", "divisions", "offices", "officials" When I run:

```
const repObj = this.props.rep.officials
console.log(repObj);
```

But when I try to access a nested value using:

When I do this.props.rep.officials[0].name,

I receive the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined 
How do I access this value?

Here is the code where I make the call:

```js
export function getRep(){
  return function(dispatch){
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key={apikeyremoved}&address=18910+porterfield+way+germantown+md+20874&levels=country&roles=legislatorLowerBody')
      .then(function(response){
        dispatch({type:"GET_REP", payload:response.data})
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        dispatch({type:"GET_REP_REJECTED", payload:err})
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
}
```

Code where i make the console log:

```js
class Rep extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    //Dispatch GET action
    this.props.getRep();
  }
  render(){
    const repObj = this.props.rep.officials[0].name
    console.log(repObj);
    return(
      <Well>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <h6>Rep name here</h6>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Well>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    rep:state.rep.rep
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({
    getRep:getRep,
    //all other actions here
  }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Rep);
```

Comment: No, I would like to get the string

Comment: Try `this.props.rep.officials[0].name`

Comment: Can we see the code where you do your request and when you console.log ?

Comment: what do you get if you do `console.log(this.prop.rep.officials);`

Comment: I have received the suggestion to run this.props.rep.officials[0].name a few times. I have edited my question to include the error message I receive when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code. Notice the presence of `[]` as well as `{}`.

Officials is an **array** containing an object. It is not a plain object.

You must first access the property of the array that represents the object.

Then you can access properties of that object.

```
this.props.rep.officials[0].name
```

Beware: The naming convention and use an an array indicates that there could be more than one value (and possibly zero). You probably want to use a loop instead of a hard coded `0`.

Comment: Thanks. When I do this.props.rep.officials[0].name, I receive the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

As `officials` is an array, `this.props.rep.officials[0].name` should return the `name` property of first obj. In officials.